# Laravel 5.2: method toBase does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I have upgraded from Laravel 5.1 to Laravel 5.2. For some reason the following error is constantly showing:

> ErrorException in Macroable.php line 74: Method toBase does not exist.

Comment: Can you post the full error, with the trace? It looks like other people have had similar issues with other functions. It usually means that something has been deprecated.

Comment: @aynber I would say that something has been removed, which is not supposed to happen in a minor release

Comment: @DaGhostmanDimitrov Actually even on Laravel's 5.3 toBase method still exist in Eloquent https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php#L1283  it just creates new collection object.

Comment: @AdmiraalTetten can You put Your code part where You're calling toBase? also model sources would be helpful. also make sure that `toBase` not called on empty or `null` result.